# How to provide an inline TextInput formatting template

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, formatting, flex4.5, textinput

I have a spark TextInput control that I would like to automatically format as the user types into it.  The format is something like `XX-XX-XXX-XXX` where each `X` is a digit.

I have create a custom `Formatter` that I am using to display these values in other locations, but I'm having trouble getting an elegant solution to provide this sort of automated formatting in the TextInput control itself.

Here is the code that I current have.  It works, but when the formatter inserts one of the hyphen, the insertion point of the TextInput does not advance, so the next digit gets inserted in the *next-to-last* position.

```
<fx:Script>
  protected function changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
  {
    itemID.text = formatter.format(itemID.text);
  }
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
  <formatters:MyFormatter id="formatter" separator="-" pattern="{[2,2,3,3]}" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Form>
  <s:FormItem label="Item ID:">
    <s:TextInput id="itemID" restrict="0-9" change="changeHandler(event)" prompt="ex. xx-xx-xxx-xxx" /> 
  </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Here is the result of typing in the characters 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 in sequence.  As you can see, the insertion point is three characters from the end which corresponds to the three inserted hyphens.

[image: Example showing incorrect character insertion]

Any suggestions on creating a smooth UX here?

Comment: I have done this by creating u custom component that extends TextInput, but I'm afraid the code is a bit bulky to paste in here. But the bottom line is that I converted the simple 'text' property to a TextFlow object, which is easier to manipulate.

Comment: I tried doing this with a Skin first, but to no avail.  I think just updating the selection in my `change` handler will be enough for now, but good to know that I'm in for a bit of work to go in whole-hog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `itemID` is a TextField based class use this:

```
itemID.setSelection(itemID.length, itemID.length);
```

It will move the caret to the end of the TF.

Comment: I was able to use this as a basis to get a solution.  I had to use the `selectRange` method instead of `setSelection` and manually handle the `Backspace` key.  Still wishing for a `labelFunction` property on `TextInput` controls.